# Does there exist a bootable Raspian Image that forgoes the need for monitor, keyboard and mouse?

Tags: bootable-media, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for an SD Card or thumb drive image that I can plug into a brand new raspberry pi which will "just work", meaning

1. I plug SD card or Thumb drive in
2. I plug ethernet cable in
3. I turn raspberry pi on
4. Unit takes a DHCP address and provides root access to SSH
5. Bonus: SSH server is advertised via bonjour/zeroconf/whatever

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes: it seems that Adafruit has us covered:

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2